# Drop down menu toggle button does not move with the menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have created a drop down menu that drops down for the top and have given it a toggle button. The button works fine with the menu moving with it as it closes and open however when the menu is open and you scroll down the page the toggle button does not move with it and I have no idea how to fix this problem. Below I will provide my HTML and CSS jode with the jquery used for the toggle.

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Josh Site</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/index.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../jQuery/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../jQuery/jquery.cycle2.video.js"></script>
<script src="../jQuery/jquery.cycle2.carousel.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<!--Skeleton for Slide out Menu-->
<body class="menu menu-open">
<header>
<nav class="menu-side">
<!--Content for Menu Side-->
<a href="#">Photography</a>
<a href="#">Film</a>
<a href="#" id="logo"><img  src="../../Assets/Josh-Logo.png" alt="Josh Meyers"></a>
<a href="#">About Me</a>
<a href="#">Contact Me</a>
<!--End of Content for Menu Side-->
</nav>
</header>
<!--End of Skeleton for Slide out Menu-->

<!--Button to Toggle "Menu Side"-->
<a href="#" class="menu-toggle"><img src="../../Assets/top-menu-icon.png" width="900px" height="50px" alt=""/></a>
<!--End of Button to Toggle "Menu Side"-->

<!--Josh Meyers about and Title-->
<div id="Josh-Meyers">
<h1>Josh Meyers</h1>
<p>Photography is the science, art and practice of creating durable images by recording light or other electromagnetic radiation, either electronically by means of an image sensor, or chemically by means of a light-sensitive material such as photographic film.[1]

Typically, a lens is used to focus the light reflected or emitted from objects into a real image on the light-sensitive surface inside a camera during a timed exposure. With an electronic image sensor, this produces an electrical charge at each pixel, which is electronically processed and stored in a digital image file for subsequent display or processing. The result with photographic emulsion is an invisible latent image, which is later chemically "developed" into a visible image, either negative or positive depending on the purpose of the photographic material and the method of processing. A negative image on film is traditionally used to photographically create a positive image on a paper base, known as a print, either by using an enlarger or by contact printing.
</p>

</div>

<!--Responsive Video Slider and Title-->
<div id="Recent-Projects">
<h1>Recent Projects</h1>
</div>
<div id="video-wrapper">
    <span class="cycle-prev">&#9001</span>
    <span class="cycle-next">&#9002</span>

<div class="cycle-slideshow"
    data-cycle-carousel-visible="3"
    data-cycle-fx="carousel"
    data-cycle-timeout="0"
    data-cycle-auto-height="640:360"
    data-cycle-prev=".cycle-prev"
    data-cycle-next=".cycle-next"
    data-cycle-slides=">iframe"
    data-cycle-youtube="true"
    data-cycle-youtube-autostart="true"
    data-cycle-pager=".cycle-pager"
    data-cycle-carousel-fluid="true"
   >

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7TccWhZ6T8c?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VPuKbzP2KNM?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DHW0hQHLpTc?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div class="cycle-pager"></div>
</div>
<!--End Responsive Video Slider and Title-->

<script>
(function() {
    var body = $('body');
    $('.menu-toggle').bind('click', function() {
        body.toggleClass('menu-open', 'toggle-open');
        return false;
});
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color:black;
    overflow:scroll;
}
/*Design for Slide Down menu*/
.menu {
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.8s ease;
    -moz-transition: top 0.8s ease;
    transition: top 0.8s ease;
    overflow:scroll;
}
.menu-open {
    top:171px;
}
.menu-open .menu-side {
    top:0px;
    }
.menu-side {
    background-color:#333;
    border-radius:0px 0px 20px 20px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    color:#fff;
    position:fixed;
    left:15%;
    top:-171px;
    width:900px;
    max-width:900px;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.8s ease;
    -moz-transition: top 0.8s ease;
    transition: top 0.8s ease;
    text-align:center;
    }
.menu-toggle {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    width:900px;
    height:50px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    top:-23.5px;
}

/*Content style for Menu Side*/
.menu-side a{
    position:relative;
    margin-top:20px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:20px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Baskerville, "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, "Century Schoolbook L", "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size:18px;
    font-style:italic;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#logo {
    border:thin solid white;
    -moz-box-shadow:30px 30px 30px 30px black;
    -webkit-box-shadow:20px 20px 20px 20px 20px black;
    box-shadow:5px 5px 20px 3px black;
}
/*Style for Josh Meyers About*/
#Josh-Meyers h1 {
    text-align:center;
color:#FFF; 
}
#Josh-Meyers p {
color:#FFF; 
}
/*Style for Video Slide Show and Title*/
#Recent-Projects {
    text-align:center;
    height:40px;
    width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
}
#Recent-Projects h1 {
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFF;
}
iframe {max-width:100%}
#video-wrapper {
    width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    height:400px;
    margin-top:5px;
}
.cycle-slideshow {
    width:100%;
    top:2%;
    margin-left:auto;
    max-width:90%;
    margin-right:auto;
    }
.cycle-prev, .cycle-next {
        font-size:40px;
        font-weight:bold;
        color:#FFF;
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        top:60%;
        z-index:999;
        cursor:pointer;
        }
.cycle-prev {left:2%;}
.cycle-next {right:2%;}
.cycle-pager { 
    text-align: center; width: 100%; z-index: 999; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top:85%
}
.cycle-pager span { 
    font-family: arial; font-size: 50px; width: 16px; height: 16px; 
    display: inline-block; color: #ddd; cursor: pointer; 
}
.cycle-pager span.cycle-pager-active { color: #D69746;}
.cycle-pager > * { cursor: pointer;}
iframe {
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
}
```

Comment: which part is the drop down

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/binxlola/9da41vfn/ the link for JS fiddle. also the drop down is (menu, menu-side, menu-open, toggle-menu)